# Visual studio code Debugger not Showing values of any string variables instead showing npos and some other things

Tags: c++, debugging, vscode-debugger

when i switched to vs code and tried to debug c++ file string variables didn't showed up like any of the variables it showed like this
npos : Numbers
_M_dataplus
_M_stringlength

or this has to do with compiler version
i'm using g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

[Example how the variable showing in the Debug session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7M4A.png)

i've tried to reinstall all of c++ extensions and vs code itself
and the problem still persists

Comment: VSCode doesn't have its own debugger, instead it relies on external debuggers like GDB or LLDB. You need to configure them to recognize and format C++ standard classes like `std::string`. See e.g. [this VSCode issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/69) for possible solutions.